# MvvmCross Fragment binding doesn't work

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have this layout:

```
<cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.droid.views.MvxListView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/accountList"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/accountlistitem"
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource AllAccounts" />
```

The layout is loaded in the fragment with this code:

```
public new AccountListViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return (AccountListViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
    set { base.ViewModel = value; }
}

public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.AccountListLayout, null);
}
```

And in my ViewModel (the Property Changed is injected via fody):

```
public ObservableCollection<Account> AllAccounts
{
    get { return accountRepository.Data; }
    set { accountRepository.Data = value; }
}
```

This won't work and won't show any data. But when I add the following lines to the fragment my data is displayed properly:

```
    var list = view.FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.accountList);
    list.ItemsSource = ViewModel.AllAccounts;
```

In another example this worked without any problems on the stable version. Also the binding seems to work in an activity, but not in a Fragment. For this project I use v4.0.0 beta2. Do I miss something?

Link to the GitHub Repository: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyManager

Thanks

Comment: Issue linked to this: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1120

Comment: I had the same issue. My project uses AppCompat features. I had to add Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.AppCompat before binding would work in v4 beta 2. Not sure if this will work for you, just mentioning as it worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything.. The interessting thing is that it only occurs in the fragment. binding of a normal activity works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I builded my own dll's out of the current development branch. Here the issue is fixed. So it seems the solution is to just wait for beta3 :)